# Multiple UIWebViews out of memory warning

Tags: ipad, memory, ios5, uiwebview

I am working with some developers who are creating an iOS 5 iPad app for us. I am familiar with coding but my no means an expert. The developers have hit a wall in their code and so I am turning to you guys to check, that there really isn't anything left to try to resolve this problem, before we give up. I've looked around and can't seem to find a straight forward resolution anywhere else, so here's the question to you guys:

The App always has to have four UIWebViews loaded. The UIWebViews need to be able to contain any website out there, be it YouTube, or whatever you can think of (i.e. something like tabbed browsing). We've tried having them on screen and off screen but either way we always run into memory problems.

I know looking to Safari isn't helpful as it's created by the mothership directly, but we're only talking about four UIWebViews here, surely this shouldn't be such a problem? Any ideas...?

Many thanks,

M

Answer (score 1):

There is only one true solution: Create your own equivalent to UIWebView that has only the features that you need, and therefore has a much smaller footprint than Apple's class. I've written such a thing, but it is not public, sorry.